# Is this Entity Data Model Design OK for simple blog project?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am creating sample blog project and designed this entity data model.

Is there anything else required, I mean in association and navigation property...

[image: Entity Data Model Design]

I have created this design on the following basis..

1. user can have many post ( 1 to many )
2. user can have many comments ( 1 to many )
3. user can have many tags (1 to many )
4. post can have many comments ( 1 to many )
5. post can have many tags ( 1 to many )

Do I need to create association for 1 to 1 between post and user
like

1. 1 post must and can have 1 user ( 1 to 1 )
2. tag must and can have 1 user ( 1 to 1 )

I am confused that I already have created 1 to many relationships between all of this and I have the required navigation properties. Is it necessary to create 1 to 1 association mentioned above?

Comment: Why are you having these `...Detail` entities?

Comment: i think its better to have another table for details rather than having one table storing all of the information... i think it would be easier for searching...if you think its not a good idea, please let me know...

Comment: I think if you expect your model to grow with multiple types of users and posts with some varied fields not much in common then we can have inheritance for such fields. Like models SuperUser NormalUser AdminUser inheriting from User and they have lots of fields uncommon which doesn't look a case here.

Comment: Also where is the blog entity? Normally we have a blog entity A user who has rights creates a blog and under that blog other users or only (himself depending on requirement) can write various posts. A blog can have many posts. Having said this, the blog entity is not mandatory and you can live without it but future modifications might be costly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. Inheritance looks unnecessary. I think if you expect your model to grow with multiple types of users and posts with some varied fields not much in common then we can have inheritance for such fields. Like models SuperUser NormalUser AdminUser inheriting from User and they have lots of fields uncommon which doesn't look a case here.
2. Blog Entity is excluded? Normally we have a blog entity A user who has rights creates a blog and under that blog other users or only (himself depending on requirement) can write various posts. A blog can have many posts. Having said this, the blog entity is not mandatory and you can live without it but future modifications might be costly.
3. The Tags and post is many to many relationship. A post can have many tags however a tag is associated with many posts. If you want to know the posts with specific tag then you need to have * to *.

Comment: ok.. i got it.. so i have to remove inheritance as this is a sample project and will not have any super user kind of stuff... also appreciate your <Post,Tag> * to * suggestion. i completely missed out that..